# Calculate Bundle Quantity in Saved Search

Tags: formula, netsuite

I need to be able to display the current quantity of a kit item in a saved search. If it's not a kit item, then do nothing.

Example:
SKU: KIT-1234 has 2 children with different amounts assigned to the kit
Child-1 = Amount for kit is 20 - Quantity in Bin = 20
Child-2 = Amount for kit is 1 - Quantity in Bin = 100

Due to only have enough children quantity to fulfill (1) kit, Kit quantity should = 1

Please help me understand the syntax for the formula to be used in a saved search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set up your item search and GROUP by Item Name or Internal ID then use the following formula(numeric) to give the number of kits you can make:

```
{memberitem.quantityonhand}/{memberquantity}
```

Set this column summary to MIN.

Understanding 'the syntax' is pretty trivial: you divide the quantity of each kit member on hand by the quantity required to make each kit, then take the minimum of the resulting calculation to give how many complete kits you can make.  In your example above you would have Child-1 returning an answer of 1 (20/20) and Child-2 returning 100 (100/1).  Taking the minimum of these gives you 1, as expected.